# No exposure on search engines

Tags: wp-query, search-engines, robots.txt

I have a blog but it doesn't show on any search engine.

Why can't my wordpress blog be seen but I am always publishing.

Answer (score 2):

Please go to `Settings > Reading` or **wp-admin/options-reading.php**

[image]

If it's not unchecked it will not allow search engines to reach.

For further modification information related to robots you can use the below plugin to modify `robots.txt` file:

[Plugin - Multipart robots.txt editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multipart-robotstxt-editor/)

To see your `robots.txt` file you would visit the link as:

`http://www.example.com/robots.txt`